# Need help in generating Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am getting the following result after joining three tables:

```
col1 col2 col3
 1    2    Pr1
 1    2    Pr2
 1    2    Pr3
```

But I need the output to be like this:

```
col1 col2 col3
 1    2    Pr1,Pr2,Pr3
```

Comment: We will need to see the sql your executing

Comment: Do you mean... SELECT col1, col2, GROUP_CONCAT(col3) FROM table GROUP BY col1,col2 ?

Comment: there in no GROUP_CONCAT in MS-SQL server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MS SQL 2005/2008:

```
select
    col1,
    col2,
    col3 = (
        select col3 + ','
        from TestTable
        for xml path('')
    )
from TestTable
group by col1, col2
```

Here you can find how to do the same in 2000 and also how to get rid of the trailing comma: [Create A Comma Delimited List From a Column](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SQLExamples/Wiki/View.aspx?title=createacommadelimitedlist)